# How to delete group of dot points in geom_point ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with plot. I want to show only dot points in group A, not in each name. Here is an example:

```
name <- c("a","b","c","d")
df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5,3), 
             value = c(seq(50,58,2),seq(60,68,2),seq(70,78,2)),
             name = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)),
             type = rep(c("a","b","c","d","r"),3))

df$name <- factor(df$name, levels = c("C","B","A"),ordered = TRUE)
ggplot(df, aes(id, value, fill = name,color = type))+
    geom_area( position = 'identity', linetype = 1, size = 1 ,colour="black") +
    geom_point(size = 8)+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL, shape = NA)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your edit suggestion. It was rejected by reviewers. But, I am happy to do the edit because it was you who made the suggestion, and your suggestion makes sense. Would you also revise your original figure and code? Then, everything will be consistent.

Comment: Here you are! Thanks!

Comment: Update done following your idea. I came across `aes.override` the other day. This is a good reminder for me to revise my knowledge. Thanks, Nicola. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am reading the question correctly, it seems that you want dots for the blue area only. In that case, you could subset the data and use it for `geom_point`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(id, value, fill = name,color = type))+
geom_area( position = 'identity', linetype = 1, size = 1 ,colour="black") +
geom_point(data = subset(df, name == "A"), size = 8) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = NULL, shape = NA)))
```

[image]